# Babelify error Cannot find module 'lodash/array/compact'

Tags: gulp, browserify, babeljs

I moving from reactify JSX compiler to Babel compiler (Babelify) using Browserify builder with Gulp system.
Now I got this error:

```
[00:17:25] Error in bundle:
[00:17:25] Error: Cannot find module 'lodash/array/compact' while parsing file:
C:\MotoGipsy\repository\motogipsy\client-trunk\public\src\scripts\app.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:336:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:278:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\MotoGipsy\repository\motogipsy\client-trunk\node_m
odules\babel-preset-es2015\node_modules\babel-plugin-transform-es2015-function-n
ame\node_modules\babel-types\lib\index.js:42:27)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:365:17)
    at require (module.js:384:17)
```

I'm using Gulp config:

```
var browserify = require('browserify'),
    babelify = require('babelify');

module.exports = function(config){
    // Create a browserify instance with proper options
    var bundler = browserify({
        cache: {}, packageCache: {}, fullPaths: true,
        debug: config.browserify.debug,
        paths: config.browserify.paths
    })
    .transform(babelify, {presets: ["es2015", "react"]});

    // Add the entry module to the bundler
    bundler.add('./public/src/scripts/app.js');

    return bundler;
};
```

And this is package.json config:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "marked": "0.3.5",
    "es5-shim": "^4.0.5",
    "extend": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.8.10",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^2.0.0",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.4.2",
    "gulp-cssmin": "^0.1.6",
    "gulp-sass": "^1.2.4",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.2.11",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.3.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.5.2",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-watch": "^3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^2.2.0",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-router": "2.0.0",
    "reflux": ">=0.3.0",
    "watchify": "^2.2.1",
    "browserify-shim": "~3.8.9",
    "react-textarea-autosize": "3.3.0",
    "react-autolink-text": "2.0.0",
    "core-js": "2.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.5.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.5.0",
    "babelify": "^7.2.0",
    "jest": "^0.1.37",
    "jest-cli": "^0.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.5.0"
  },
```

I'm really confused about this situation. Please let me know why this dependency doesn't go with Babel plugins? How can I fix this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue but with running the Frisby testing framework. Did you get this fixed? As the other solutions didn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the reason was in an outdated NPM. So:

```bash
$ sudo npm install -g npm
```

solved my problems.

No just run `npm install` again to reinstall dependencies

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered similar problem. In my gulp file it was used like

```
var compact = require('lodash/array/compact')
compact(assetTasks.map(matchFilter))
```

But with new lodash you can't use compact module as before. So below solved my problem.

```
var array = require('lodash/array')
array.compact(assetTasks.map(matchFilter))
```